# kubernetes nginx ingress controller rewrites

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, mockserver

We have deployed a mockserver on kubernetes. Currently, we only have one hostname which is shared by couple other applications (using a different path). However, the dashboard is not working because of the css location. What's the best way to solve this problem?

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (), hostname/mockserver/dashboard/static/css/main.477cab2a.chunk.css
```

The ingress manifest:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: mock-server
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-ingress-protected
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: mock-server-ingress
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  rules:
    - host: hostname
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: mock-server-svc
              servicePort: 80
            path: /testing(/|$)(.*)
```

This works fine if I request resource like `hostname/testing/mockserver/expectation`, the rewrites will be sending `/mockserver/exepctation` to the backend.

However, if for path `hostname/testing/mockserver/dashboard`, it is a html page which will loads `hostname/mockserver/dashboard` which doesn't exist. I can't wrap my head around this. Should I create another ingress with path `/mockserver` just to serve the css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rewrite is working as expected. However,
there are some options you can choose from:

1. Create a second rule for the `/mockserver` (the simplest solution).
2. Play with capture groups:

> Captured groups are saved in numbered placeholders, chronologically,
> in the form $1, $2 ... $n. These placeholders can be used as
> parameters in the rewrite-target annotation.

3. Use a [paid solution](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/rewrites#syntax).

The easiest would be to go for option 1 and create a second rule which would satisfy the path for the css.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I end up creating another ingress with different path, and it works perfectly fine.